# AJAX failing for some users only

Tags: jquery, ajax

For a fraction of users, AJAX request is going to the error function, it is {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} error. CORS can be ruled out here since it is happening to a very small set of users. I have checked the user agents of these users, and they are mostly on latest version of Chrome Android. FormData is not a problem either, I have put a function where it is logged if that is not available in user's device.

Also, the first function works perfectly fine, it's the issue with the second function.

Below is my code:

```
$('#details-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/profile/document",
        data: {'name': name, 'email': email},
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(value) {
            console.log('works');
        },
        error: function(value) {
            shareLog(value); //I use this to know how many users are affected
            showErrorMessage('Error occurred. Please try again later.');
        }
    });
}); //This function works perfectly okay for all users

$('#document-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formDataDocument = new FormData();
    var doc = $('#doc')[0].files;
    formDataDocument.append('doc', doc[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/profile/document",
        data: formDataDocument,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(value) {
            console.log('works');
        },
        error: function(value) {
            shareLog(value); //I use this to know how many users are affected
            showErrorMessage('Error occurred. Please try again later.');
        }
    });
}); //This function doesn't work with some users
```

Major problem is I have tried this on multiple devices and this never happens with me so it is very difficult to troubleshoot. I have been facing this issue since a long time and have accessed almost all related answers here but none of them worked for me.

Can you please provide some ideas on why this might be happening? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Outputting more detail than `'Function failed'` might be a start

Comment: Sorry about that. I return ‘value’ and that gives me readystate 0 status 0 error.

Comment: "CORS can be ruled out here since it is happening to a very small set of users" Why does the fact that it is happening to a very small set of users rule out CORS? That small set of users might be on a particular segment of the network that uses a proxy to connect to the web server that isn't accounted for it the allowed origins.

Comment: Okay, that may be the case. However, I had earlier set origin to Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" and the issue still continued.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to set the `contentType` and `processData` to `false` here?